# match strings between outer single quotes

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following data:

```
compose '`' 'A' to '\C0'
compose '`' 'a' to '\E0'
compose '\'' 'A' to '\C1'
compose '\'' 'a' to '\E1'
compose '^' 'A' to '\C2'
compose '^' 'a' to '\E2'
```

All the quotes are single quotes

I have this regex

```
\'(\\.|[^\'])*\'
```

It matches what I want in the full matches but it includes the outer single quotes.

This string `compose '\'' 'A' to '\C1'` gives me `'\''` and `'A'` and `'\C1'` but I need `\'` and `A` and `\C1`

I could get away with removing the first and last single quote from the string but I'd like to do it with regex.

How can I obtain the result I want please?

As for the regex engine, it's for use in a qt5 core application, so c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs a slight modification, capturing a group multiple times doesn't really work. What you really want is a group containing zero or more copies of your `\\.|[^\']` expresssion. You can do this with a non capturing group which is written by adding `?:` inside the opening parenthesis of the group. The full regex is then:

```
\'((?:\\.|[^\'])*)\'
```

You can try it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/n0iksu/1).

Comment: Thx. I chose yours as the accepted answer as is processes slightly faster than Timo's regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not optimal. I don't know what exactly you are allowed to match, but from the data that you have given us this regex will do the trick: `\s\'(\S+?\'?)\'`.

```
std::regex reg(R"(\s\'(\S+?\'?)\')");
std::string input = R"(
compose '`' 'A' to '\C0'
compose '`' 'a' to '\E0'
compose '\'' 'A' to '\C1'
compose '\'' 'a' to '\E1'
compose '^' 'A' to '\C2'
compose '^' 'a' to '\E2')";

auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), reg);
auto end = std::sregex_iterator();
for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    std::cout << (*it)[1].str() << '\n';
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/GPPXAO) is a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a group in your regex - you can read it.

If you have `std::smatch` called `results` (or whatever you use as [`std::match_results`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results)), then [`results[1]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at) will give you the first (and only) group - provided that string was actually matched, otherwise it's UB.

```
std::regex r {"\'(\\.|[^\'])*\'"};
std::string input = "compose '`' 'A' to '\\C0'";
std::smatch results;
if(std::regex_search(input, results, r)) {
    std::cout << results[0] << std::endl  //full match
              << results[1] << std::endl; //first group
}
```

Comment: I think it's not 100% correct. Paste the data and the regex in regex101.com and you'll see. The 3th line in the data for example gives wrong results.

Comment: correction: the 3th item per line gives wrong results in results[1]